# How do you use counting sort to sort just one row from an 2d array in c

Tags: c

```
void suma_rand(int (*a)[50], int n, int m){

int i, j, sum1, max_rand=-1;

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    sum1 = 0;
    for(j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
        sum1 = sum1 + a[i][j];


    }
    if(max_rand<sum1)
```

{

```
 max_rand=sum1;
 }
```

In the function above I find the sum of every row and find the row with the biggest sum, now how do I use counting sort to sort the elements of the row which I found to have the biggest sum?

Comment: sum is independent on ordering elements of array. How could sorting help?

Comment: @hurricanek218 - In the _function above_ you don't lastingly _find the row with the biggest sum_, since you store only _the biggest sum_, not its row index. Moreover, in order to use _counting sort_ on this row, you also have to store the biggest element of the row.

Comment: For me your question is a bit hard to read. I understood your question like this, but I'm not sure if that is what you wanted: I have the function above, finding the highest sum. What can I do to sort the array depending on the row sum?

Comment: @Armali I think you are right but how should I store the index of the row with the biggest sum?

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you, @Armali you we're right i just had to store the index and pass it as a pointer to the countig sort algorithm <3